# Qml button fix size

Tags: qml

I have made list whose delegate is RowLayout consist of Button. The list takes data from cpp.

My problem is the button variable width. The button side changed based on data. I want to keep fix button side and wrap text

Answer (score 2):

To give your `Button` a fixed width, just set the property with the same name to a fixed value.

The `Button` has a `contentItem` that is a `Text`. You can change the `wrapMode` there to [`Text.WordWrap`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-text.html#wrapMode-prop)

As the `contentItem` is of type `Item` you can't set the `wrapMode` like this:

```
Button {
    width: 100
    text:  'Very very long button description.'
    contentItem.wrapMode: Text.WordWrap // Won't work
}
```

Instead you might use `Component.onCompleted` like this:

```
Button {
    width: 100
    text:  'Very very long button description.'
    Component.onCompleted: contentItem.wrapMode = Text.WordWrap
}
```